# LINQ - Distinct is ignored?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, distinct, gethashcode

So I have a problem with my LINQ code, where I have to select a Distinct data set, I implement the following `IEqualityComparer`:

```
public class ProjectRoleComparer : IEqualityComparer<ProjectUserRoleMap>
{
    public bool Equals(ProjectUserRoleMap x, ProjectUserRoleMap y)
    {
        return x.RoleID.Equals(y.RoleID);
    }
    public int GetHashCode(ProjectUserRoleMap obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

In this context, I wish to retrieve a bunch of `ProjectUserRoleMap` objects related to a given Project, identified by it's ID, I only want one `ProjectUserRoleMap` per unique `RoleID`, but my strict instruction to perform a distinct select on the `RoleID` is ignored. I am totally clueless as to why this is the case, and do not understand LINQ enough to think of a workaround. Here is the calling code:

```
ProjectRoleComparer prCom = new ProjectRoleComparer();

IEnumerable<ProjectUserRoleMap> roleList = ProjectData.AllProjectUserRoleMap.Where(x => x.ProjectID == id).Distinct(prCom);
```

This code gives me 6 entries, when the number of entries I **know** I want is just 4. **Am I doing something wrong with my usage of LINQ?**

For reference, the `ProjectUserRoleMap` object has a RoleID, (int)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your implementation of `GetHashCode` is wrong. Return `obj.RoleID.GetHashCode();`

Background:
Code that consumes an `IEqualityComparer<T>` usually first compares the hash codes of two objects. Only if those hash codes are the same `Equals` is called.
It is implemented like this, because two *unequal* objects can have the *same* hash key, but two *equal* objects never can have *different* hash keys - if `GetHashCode()` is implemented correctly.
This knowledge is used to improve the efficiency and performance of the comparison as implementations of `GetHashCode` are supposed to be fast, cheap operations.

Comment: Whoa! So simple! How did I miss that? Works perfect, as intended now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
public int GetHashCode(ProjectUserRoleMap obj)
{
    return obj.RoleID.GetHashCode();
}
```