# IEquatable on POCO identity field

Tags: c#, poco, iequalitycomparer, iequatable

I have POCOs from a SQL Server database that have an identity ID field. I would like to implement IEquatable so I can check if they're the same record, use `.Contains()` on `List<T>`  etc.

Assuming I will never need to compare unsaved instances, is it sufficient to just implement using:

```
    public bool Equals(MyClass other)
    {
        return this.ID == other.ID;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.ID;
    }
```

I'm about to do this, but just wanted to check that's fine, as I'm not 100% sure what GetHashCode has to do with it, or if there are any other considerations (such as the "unsaved instance" one, which I can discard) that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16147925/572644) to learn what `GetHashCode` is about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override `GetHashCode()` whenever you override `Equals()` (which you should also do when you implement `IEquatable<T>`) so that classes that rely on it, such as  `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, can handle it correctly.  It's one of those inner details that annoyingly leaks out. [More information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden).

As for whether comparing your IDs is sufficient for determining equality, if you're absolutely sure that two entities with the same ID should be considered equivalent under all circumstances, then go for it. That's a question only the requirements of your application can answer.  I've done it quite a few times myself, almost always with read-only entities.

I would implement it this way:

```
// IEquatable<MyClass> implementation
public bool Equals(MyClass other) 
{
  if (other == null) 
  {
    return false;
  }

  return this.ID == other.ID;
}

// Override of default Object.Equals()
public override bool Equals(object other) 
{
  return this.Equals(other as MyClass);
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
  // Call ID.GetHashCode() because ID may not always be int,
  // and the ID type might have a more useful implementation
  // of GetHashCode() to offer.
  return this.ID.GetHashCode(); 
}
```

You should probably also override the `==` and `!=` operators in this case.  You can always use `Object.ReferenceEquals()` if you want to distinguish between two distinct references with the same ID.

Comment: Microsoft's doc for [Object.GetHashCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Object_GetHashCode) offers strategies for implementing `GetHashCode`. In particular, for hashing a  value that ***is*** numeric, the "Examples" section begins with: *"One of the simplest ways to compute a hash code for a numeric value that has the same or a smaller range than the [Int32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32?view=netframework-4.7.1) type is to simply return that value."*

Answer (score 1):

If, by your businessrules, your objects are equal to each other when their ID's are equal, than you are doing just fine!

The hashcode of an object state that every object with a different state, should return a different hashcode. This hashcode is not unique, but we can try to make them as different as possible. Just check out the hashcode of strings `"Hello".GetHashCode()` and `"Goodbye".GetHashCode()`.

HashCode is used in some collections, like `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<K,V>` and `System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<T>`. By using this hashcode, those dictionary can search and find an item very fast (almost an O(1)-operation) by using this 'unique' hashcode. Calculate this hashcode by using the hashcodes of the field(s) of your entity.

If you implement `IEquatable<T>.Equals`, also override `Equals(object)`.